# matplotlib contourchart interpolated z-values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I create a `matplotlib` contour chart with `cs = ax.contour(x, y, z)`, which returns `QuadContourSet` object. I am intercepting the mouse events with `motion_notify_event` which allows getting the `x`-values and `y`-values with `event.xdata` and `event.ydata`. Would it be possible for `x` and `y` coordinates of the mouse cursor to get also the interpolated `z`-values corresponding to the contour chart (from the returned `QuadContourSet` object)? I have searched but there is not much documentation on `QuadContourSet`available. Or do I have to somehow calculate it manually from the original array of `z` values? I assume this can would not be very easy in a general case with for example logarithmic scaled axes etc. Or is there any hint which could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have to interpolate the values myself. As far as I am using linear axes, this works pretty well with sufficient accuracy even for very sparse grid. Note that below is my naive attempt for bilinear interpolation, if you happen to have better algorithm (please without other dependencies like scipy etc.), please post it. I have not yet tested this on logarithmic axes though...

```
# note that z-data are indexed with pair (y, x) rather than (x, y)
pos = event.inaxes.transAxes.inverted().transform([event.x, event.y])
# relative coordinates in <0, 1>
rx = pos[0] * (self.__data.shape[1] - 1)
ry = pos[1] * (self.__data.shape[0] - 1)
# calculate the corner coordinates
rxLow, rxHigh = math.floor(rx), math.ceil(rx)
ryLow, ryHigh = math.floor(ry), math.ceil(ry)
# weights based on the distance
wxLow, wyLow = 1.0 - rx + rxLow, 1.0 - ry + ryLow
wxHigh, wyHigh = 1.0 - rxHigh + rx, 1.0 - ryHigh + ry
# adjust in case rxLow == rxHigh or ryLow == ryHigh
wx = wxLow + wxHigh
wy = wyLow + wyHigh
wxLow /= wx
wxHigh /= wx
wyLow /= wy
wyHigh /= wy
# get the corner data
z00 = self.__data[ryLow, rxLow]
z01 = self.__data[ryHigh, rxLow]
z10 = self.__data[ryLow, rxHigh]
z11 = self.__data[ryHigh, rxHigh]
# interpolate
zxLow = z00 * wyLow + z01 * wyHigh
zxHigh = z10 * wyLow + z11 * wyHigh
z = zxLow * wxLow + zxHigh * wxHigh  # the interpolated value
```